# Is it possible to change KNotes/KJots data file location?

Tags: kubuntu

Kubuntu 18.04: I love KJots and have built up a very useful (to me) little database of notes, instructions, reminders, todo lists etc. that I would have previously kept on bits of paper, postit notes and odd pages in an excerside book.

But I am unhappy that my valuable data is kept in some rather obscure hidden directory, I would much rather it was in ~/jots or something similarly obvious. At the moment I don't fancy my chances of recovering my notes from a backup if something were to go wrong.

Is it possible to change the note datafile location? It seems tied up in some overly-complicated way that I do not understand with akonadi and sql.

Comment: Can you not figure out which file is storing your data? Suppose you close all other applications, especially browsers, create something using `kjots`, save your work, and then immediately run `find -newermt "2 minute ago"` from a terminal. The output should let you know where things are saved. I'm sure you have some sort of backup application. Add the relevant file(s) to the list of things you backup. I don't use `kjots` myself and so can't be helpful in a specific way!

Comment: @DK Bose: yes I know the files that change if I change a note and my backup scripts do indeed back them up. But I am not clear how the filenames are made up by KNotes/KJots or, more importantly, how I would persuade a new installation to use the old files in the event of a catastrophe. Where backups are concerned I prefer things to be simple and obvious, not burried deep in a hidden ~/.local directory with a non-obvious filename :-)